# How to handle browser back button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my application, First I need to select an option and press next button.
Then I click on browser provided back button. That option should be selected when I come back to that page.
How can we do this with javascript?

Comment: Please share some code so someone could assist you into the wonderful world of local/session storage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Jquery/JS Session object` to store your data. In your scenario whenever you select the option just update your storage object `localStorage.setItem("optionVal", "test");`
so when you go next and comeback to using back button just check if the `optionVal is not null` and has some value if it has some value just bind it with the drop down DOM. To check/get data you need to use `localStorage.getItem("lastname");` since you have not provided I can just tell you the approach. Here are some links that might help:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Wizard for this process like payment option in e-commence site

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-and-validation

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/

if you send the whole scenario then may me help with complete code